# How to group an array on an attribute to attain each groups aggregate value at a specific key using javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, group-by, underscore.js

I'd like to take the below array and identify all the unique values of 'fruit', and identify the corresponding counts for those fruit.

For example, in the below array, we know that there are three fruit (apples, bananas, and cherries) and that we have 2 apples, 10 bananas, and 5 cherries.

```
var input_data = [{"count":1,"fruit":"apple"},{"count":1,"fruit":"apple"},{"count":10,"fruit":"banana"},{"count":5,"fruit":"cherry"}]
```

Based on the above input, I'd like to achieve the below outputs:

```
desired_output_1 = ['apple','banana','cherry']

desired_output_2 = [2,10,5]
```

I was able to get desired_output_1 with the following function that I used from underscore.js, but I'm not sure how to attain desired_output_2.

```
_.uniq(_.pluck(input_data,'fruit'))
```

As a result, I really would like a way to attain [2,10,5] based on count for the above.

Answer (score 0):

```
var input_data = [{"count":1,"fruit":"apple"},{"count":1,"fruit":"apple"},{"count":10,"fruit":"banana"},{"count":5,"fruit":"cherry"}];

var fruits = [];
var counts = [];

for (var i in input_data) {
    var index = fruits.indexOf(input_data[i].fruit);
    if (index == -1) {
        fruits.push(input_data[i].fruit)
        counts.push(input_data[i].count);
    } else {
        counts[index] += input_data[i].count;
    }
}

console.log(fruits, counts);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var data = [{
  "count": 1,
  "fruit": "apple"
}, {
  "count": 1,
  "fruit": "apple"
}, {
  "count": 10,
  "fruit": "banana"
}, {
  "count": 5,
  "fruit": "cherry"
}];

var fruits = [];
var counts = [];
for (var i in data) {
    var index = fruits.indexOf(data[i].fruit);
    if (index == -1) {
        fruits.push(data[i].fruit)
        counts.push(data[i].count);
    } else {
        counts[index] = counts[index] + data[i].count;
    }
}

console.log(fruits , counts);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may not need underscore/lodash :)

```js
    var input_data = [
      {"count":1,"fruit":"apple"},
      {"count":1,"fruit":"apple"},
      {"count":10,"fruit":"banana"},
      {"count":5,"fruit":"cherry"}
    ];
    
    
    var result = input_data.reduce(function ( acc, current ) {
      if( !acc[current.fruit] ) {
        acc[current.fruit] = 0;
      }
      acc[current.fruit] += current.count;
      return acc;
    }, {});
    
    console.log(result);
```

Output is an object instead of two arrays. This will keep the fruit <-> count relation.